# Best laptop for elemental os

Tags: hardware

There may any one help me with a laptop choice because am new to elemental os

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many laptops that have any sort of official support for elementary OS.

There are brands of laptops that come with a Linux distribution pre-installed. Those likely also work fine with elementary OS. For example:

- https://entroware.com/
- https://slimbook.es/en/
- https://system76.com/

The majority of laptops that come with Windows preinstalled can run Linux distributions like elementary OS with little to no problems. Some may require additional fixes to get Wi-Fi and such working. Very new laptop models that come with cutting-edge hardware might not fully function on Linux (yet) or require you to install a newer Linux kernel.

To find information about the compatibility of a specific laptop model you'll have to do some research yourself, and/or ask the manufacturer.

elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, so if a laptop works well with Ubuntu, it likely works well with elementary OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

https://puri.sm/ will prob work fine since it comes with PureOS pre-installed, which is also a fork of Ubuntu afaik.

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, I have a Dell XPS 9550 and elementary OS works perfectly out of the box on it. Everything like WiFi, F keys, touchpad, Bluetooth, external ports... not a single problem or additional drivers needed.